# Create-React-App how do I import all SCSS files from a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I'm trying to port a Ruby on Rails app to Node.js with create-react-app, but I'm a bit stuck on preprocessing .scss files from a specified directory. I have a structure like this: src/css/styles.scss and src/css/app/ directory which contains some custom scss files. All the imports are inside styles.scss. Here they are:

```
@import 'customvars';
@import 'tooltipster-sideTip-punk.min';
@import 'tooltipster.bundle.min';
@import "./app/*";
```

I have node-sass-chokidar installed so the scss are processed just fine but once it gets to a directory (app in this case) I get this error:

> {   "status": 1,   "file":
>   "D:/Dropbox/WebStorm/project_incognito/src/css/styles.scss",   "line":
>   4,   "column": 1,   "message": "File to import not found or
>   unreadable: ./app/*.\nParent style sheet:
>   D:/Dropbox/WebStorm/project_incognito/src/css/styles.scss",
>
>   "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   ./app/*.\n       Parent style sheet:
>   D:/Dropbox/WebStorm/project_incognito/src/css/styles.scss\n        on
>   line 4 of src/c ss/styles.scss\n>> @import \"./app/*\";\n   ^\n" }

I did some googling and found this solution:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader

But I just can't figure out how to configure it. The docs say it can be used in two ways. The first one is to add module like this:

```
{
  module: {
    preloaders: [{
      test: /\.scss/,
      loader: 'import-glob-loader'
    }]
  }
}
```

But where do I have to add this? I tried to add it to react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js
But once I try to add something there, WebStorm says "This file does not belong to the project"

The second way is to do this:

```
require('style!css!sass!import-glob!foo/bar.scss')
```

Which is also unclear to me. Where do I have to add a line like this?

Do I have to override webpack.config.js in some way and install something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-config? 
What is the correct way to add modules like that?

Comment: have you included style/css/sass loader plugins for webpack? That might actually be a good alternative to import-glob-loader

Comment: where to include them? And how? All I've done for scss so far is installed node-sass-chokidar and modified my package.json file's scripts section like this: `"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }`

Comment: ok so just to double check here, you are using webpack?

Comment: @TinusWagner he is, it's `create-react-app` so, yeah.

Comment: I'm using Create-React-App solution. It includes webpack as I can see. But I'm not really sure about anything yet since it's my second day with react and everything is new to me (except for javascript itself)

Comment: right you are at @ickyrr

Comment: I read the documentation of older versions and newest one, nothing found about this specific configuration. I'm having same issue and it's not viable eject CRA. I've opened a issue at its repo, you can subscribe for updates: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7732